# Ruby: How to specify class in loop block argument

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering how I can specify the object type of the loop block argument.

Basically, I'd like to be able to say:

```
my_collection = MyCollection.new
my_collection.each do |my_collection_object|
    # how can I call method1 and method2 of my_collection_object?
    my_collection_object.method1
    my_collection_object.method2
    etc...
end
```

I presume that I should write my own iteration loop method (#each) to my own collection class, but since I'm a complete noob, I can't figure out where to start.  Please give me guidance.  Thanks for help!

EDIT:
I want to clarify my non-understanding a little further.  To complete above I have below class I want to return for the #each method block argument of `MyCollection` object.

If I just call method1 and method2 from snippet code above, does it automatically know where to look for method1 and method2 then?  How does it do that?  (Sorry if original question is slightly changed)

```
class My_Collection_Object
    def method1
    ...
    end
    def method2
    ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Mmmmh I didn't understand =) Why can't you call those methods?

Comment: Me neither. You should put your question more clearly.

Comment: So: you have a `MyCollection` class and you want to iterate through some instances of it? Or through some instance attributes? Can you share with us your `MyCollection` implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about passing type information into the block, because Ruby uses [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Ruby).

> In duck typing, a programmer is only concerned with ensuring that objects behave as demanded of them in a given context, rather than ensuring that they are of a specific type.

That means you don't need to worry about passing the type into the block, as the Ruby interpreter will know if the method exists at runtime. If you try to use `method1` and `method2` on a type that doesn't have those methods defined, it will simply throw an exception.